# Date counter for daily returns using trading days

Tags: r, finance

I have a time series dataset. This is a sample of the data:

```
      firm   evntdate       date evntdum      ret  mrktret bef_sum

1 03251110 1989-08-01 1989-02-23       1 -0.00498  0.00053     110
2 03251110 1989-08-01 1989-02-24       1 -0.00500 -0.00494     110
3 03251110 1989-08-01 1989-02-27       1  0.00503 -0.00125     110
4 03251110 1989-08-01 1989-02-28       1  0.00500  0.00392     110
5 03251110 1989-08-01 1989-03-01       1 -0.00498 -0.00040     110
6 03251110 1989-08-01 1989-03-02       1  0.00000  0.00503     110
```

The dataset includes information about a firm ('firm') and event date ('evntdate'). For each event date, there are several daily returns ('ret') prior to the event date, therefore for each specific event, there has to be a unique firm and event date repeated for as many times as I have daily returns. The 'bef_sum' is a number indicating the number of daily returns prior to the event date which repeats itself each row if it belongs to the same firm/event date.

What I want to do is to create another column that will create a date counter, so that the first daily return (based in 'date') for a specific combination of firm/evndate will be -110 the next one -109 (because this counter is relative to the event date), and so fort. The difficulty I have is that this counter should be independent for each firm/evntdate, I cannot use a simple subtraction from the event date minus date because these are trading days, so holidays/weekends should not be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to get what you want using the `plyr` package (I'm showing it on a sample data-frame I created, dropping columns not relevant to this problem, such as returns, etc):

```
> require(plyr)
> ddply( df, .(firm, evntdate), transform, 
         DateCount = -1 - bef_sum + seq_along( bef_sum))

   firm   evntdate       date bef_sum DateCount
1     1 1989-08-01 1989-07-01       7        -7
2     1 1989-08-01 1989-07-04       7        -6
3     1 1989-08-01 1989-07-07       7        -5
4     1 1989-08-01 1989-07-10       7        -4
5     1 1989-08-01 1989-07-13       7        -3
6     1 1989-08-01 1989-07-16       7        -2
7     1 1989-08-01 1989-07-19       7        -1
8     1 1990-08-01 1990-07-01       5        -5
9     1 1990-08-01 1990-07-05       5        -4
10    1 1990-08-01 1990-07-09       5        -3
11    1 1990-08-01 1990-07-13       5        -2
12    1 1990-08-01 1990-07-17       5        -1
```

Also in general you can deal with holidays and weekends, etc, using a package `fCalendar` -- if you used such a package, you could directly count the number of "trading days" between `evntdate` and `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried functions from the [timeDate library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/index.html)?  For example, the function holidayNYSE() returns the NYSE's holidays for a given year.  You could use this list to remove non-applicable days.

Comment: I did take a look at it. It does not work for me because it will still not compute the counter, it will just let me know the days the specific exchange was closed. What I need is a counter indicating the 'nth' observation prior to the event date. For example, 0 will indicate that that observation has information for the event date, -10 will be the 10th observation before the event date, which is not the same as 10 days before the event day because we are talking about trading days. Thank you!